# Multilingual Url sharing in twitter

Tags: twitter

I wanted to share a url which contains both english and  urdu words.  After tweeting, the url gets misaligned. We assume tweeter recognise the whole content as urdu and so it writes it from right to left.

Url : [https://ruralindiaonline.org/articles/آزادی-کی-دس-کہانیاں/](https://ruralindiaonline.org/articles/%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B3-%DA%A9%DB%81%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%A7%DA%BA/)

[image]

But this is how it comes on sharing the tweet.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Kindly help us on this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Twitter is getting confused here.

You need to [URL Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the Urdu portion of the URL - for example:

`https://ruralindiaonline.org/articles/%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B3-%DA%A9%DB%81%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%A7%DA%BA`